# make schema fields read-only in Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: 2011, cme, schema

what would be the best approach to create a 'read-only' schema field in Tridion 2011? There was a good extension for 5.3/2009 (http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/readonlyfields.aspx), but how should we proceed with T2011?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A GUI Extension is good way to do this in Tridion 2011. There's a useful example here:

http://yoavniran.wordpress.com/2010/08/23/the-read-only-fields-tridion-gui-extension/

**Update**

As Nuno pointed out the example I provided is no use to you as its for Tridion 2009.

A GUI extension remains a valid approach, you just need a better example.

In the below Albert shows how to load some JavaScript for the Component Edit view.

http://albertromkes.com/2012/01/30/tridion-gui-extensions-how-to-load-a-javascript-without-showing-a-gui-element/

Once you have your code executing in the Component Edit view you can mimic the approach in the 2009 example, marking schema fields with a [READONLY] suffix.

Then in your custom JS locate the fields that have a label element that contains [READONLY].

Once you have this, the input itself will be a child element, to which you can add the disabled attribute.

That covers standard text fields, you might have to think different for other field types - but again the 2009 example will guide you!

Comment: That's an example for Tridion 2009, OP specifically asked for 2011.